# Can a demon temporarily borrow a person's entire life through a Pact?

Tags: demon-the-descent

A pact can give a demon a temporary cover.  In the book *Demon: Interface*, an example of a transferable pact is given:

> Gaunt pays Yuri a visit and promises to save his business by improving Yuri’s skill and injecting cash, in exchange for borrowing it for a week at an unspecified future date. Gaunt makes it clear that it won’t be him taking the cab over himself.
>
> Yuri: Asset (Resources 2) + 2, Asset (Professional Training: Cab Driver 4) +2
>
> Gaunt: Duration (week) 0, Cover (Medial) 2, Transfer Pact 2
>
> *Onyx Path Publishing. Demon: Interface (Chronicles of Darkness)*

During the period that a demon borrows Yuri's taxi business, I assume Yuri just loses that part of his reality, and the demon assumes it for the week.  The text is unclear if Yuri gains resources permanently or not, but the demon only gets the cover for a week.

The practical effect I would like to create is a "temporary Soul Pact" in which the demon steps into the entire person (as in a Soul Pact) but only for a limited time.  Of course, this isn't possible in a normal Soul Pact.  Is there a way to do this within the rules now?

Why I want this:
I would like to have a storyline where an agency gives a PC a temporary cover of a millionaire, "Bruce Stark," so that the PC can attend a mysterious auction.  Stark has a pact with the agency for the wealth, but the agency has the right to "borrow" his reality for short times.   This gives dramatic opportunities like those in spy films when a spy is disguised as someone famous and has to pull off the impersonation.

Answer (score 4):

### Sleeve Integrator

The most straightforward way to achieve this effect is with the *Sleeve Integrator* Merit, from *Flowers of Hell, the Demon Player's Guide*, page 130.

This Merit, available to Stigmatics only, allows a Stigmatic to be "used like a Cover" with their consent. Note that this doesn't require a formal Pact, but produces the desired effect.

In game, the agency and the Stigmatic may have a "business deal", wherein they work together to propel him to fiduciary success. He enjoys a taste of demonic power (and a lifestyle of wealth); they gain access to his life as a Cover, one day at a time.

Furthermore, some Demons know the *Inflict Stigmata* Exploit (DtD, page 168), and merits can be gained through Pacts - so Bruce could have potentially come from anywhere.